# MVC Model binding of complex objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, binding, model, action

I've read and implemented many answers here and around the web but had no luck..

My model looks something like this:

```
public class CampaignModel : BaseModel
{
    .
    .
    public List<TreeItem> Countries { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
```

In the view i have:

```
@foreach (var country in Model.Countries.Select((value,i)=> new {i, value}))
{
<input type="checkbox" name="campaign.Countries[@country.i].Id" value="@country.value.Id" @(country.value.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
}
```

At the action I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateTargeting(CampaignModel campaign)
{
    return View(campaign);
}
```

But the 'Countries' property turns out null.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: You don't need the `campaign.` prefix in the name of the checkboxes.

Comment: Can you give the detail of TreeItem class , i think this is not getting intialized.Try doing that in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you need to use `Model` instead of `campaign` in the name attributes, like below:

`name="@Model.Countries[@country.i].Id"`

And right now your `foreach` loop will generate the html code like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" checked=""checked""/>
```

With above code, the model binding will not work, that's why you got null values when you submitted the form. You need something like below:

```
<input id="Countries_0__IsSelected" name="Countries[0].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
<input name="Countries[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false"/>
<input checked="checked" id="Countries_1__IsSelected" name="Countries[1].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
<input name="Countries[1].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

So I suggest you to use `Razor` syntax, like below:

```
foreach (var country in Model.Countries.Select((value,i)=> new {i, value}))
{
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Countries[@country.i].IsSelected )    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lin, what you wrote helped me come out with the solution below!

Comment: Note to others who tried this: doesn't work for IEnumerable or ICollection of Countries, only on List or Array

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding 2 more hidden fields to identify the exact checkbox.

The TreeItem lolks like this:

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public List<TreeItem> Leafes { get; set; }

    public TreeItem() { }

    public TreeItem(int id, string title, bool selected = false, List<TreeItem> leafes = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        IsSelected = selected;
        Leafes = leafes;
    }
}
```

The full solution looks like this (I demonstrate a a 2 level hierarchy):

```
<ul id="devicesList">
    @foreach (var brand in Model.DeviceBrands.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
    { 
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].IsSelected)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].Title)
                        <label><b>@brand.value.Title</b></label>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var deviceModel in brand.value.Leafes.Select((value, j) => new { j, value }))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].Leafes[@deviceModel.j].IsSelected)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].Leafes[@deviceModel.j].Id)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceBrands[@brand.i].Leafes[@deviceModel.j].Title)
                                    <label>@deviceModel.value.Title</label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Thanks Lin!